# Is there a way to show the direction of a route?

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, route

I use pgrouting and openstreetmaps. I would like to know if there is a way to show the direction of the route on the map (e.g. something like this ---->---- or any other way, or idea)

Comment: do you want to use a specific GIS?

Comment: I use openlayers

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you use to render your map.

- In case you use Mapserver, this example might help you:  http://mapserver.org/mapfile/symbology/construction.html#tricks
- For Geoserver here is some tutorial:
  http://blog.geoserver.org/2009/04/02/follow-the-arrows/